# Access Management Claims error

Tags: sites-9.5, access-management

We configured Access Management with Azure OpenID provider, Now we are getting the below error.
can you please suggest how to resolve it.

Below are claims configured
"usernameClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
"fullNameClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"

'Username' claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress' is missing.Check the logs for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you indeed configured the user name to be in a claim called "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", but the Identity Provider did not provide such a claim (for the user trying to log in).

You should use the "Validate" button on the Identity Provider in Access Management in order to see the claims which are provided by the IDP.

Comment: Thank you Rick, once we update usernameClaim as "upn" and  fullNameClaim as "name" issue resolved.